# FLEX when read large token, meet buffer overflow error

Tags: overflow, flex-lexer

My parser meets below error when meet a very large token:
"input buffer overflow, can't enlarge buffer because scanner uses REJECT"

1) The default YY_BUF_SIZE is 16k, it's no error if I change this value bigger, but it can't guarantee it's OK next time since the input can have bigger token; Also I find if I enlarge YY_BUF_SIZE value, the parser performance is affected and it's slower than before.

2) yytext should be %pointer from [the instructions here](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Matching.html) to overcome this error, but I tried it and it didn't work. Seems my yytext is already pointer.

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? I think Flex should allow user unlimited token size which just dependent on the system memory or dynamic memory stack capacity. Appreciate very much for any suggestion or idea!

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you what you need to know, I think. Normally, `flex` can resize the buffer up to the limit of available memory, but that's not the case if you use the `REJECT` action (because the scanner needs to maintain a state stack to implement `REJECT` and the state stack is not resizable).

In general, `flex` is not optimized for huge tokens, and in some cases huge tokens can slow `flex` down quite a lot. `REJECT` also slows `flex` down. So your best solution is to avoid matching huge tokens; for example, strings and comments can be tokenized one line at a time instead of being tokenized as one enormous token.

If you really need to be able to handle arbitrarily-long single tokens, you'll have to figure out how to avoid `REJECT`.